# NPM unmet peer dependency on every package i try to install

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am very new to the frustrating world of NPM.

I have run `create-react-app`, it installs except for the following warning messages

```sh
yarn add v1.17.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > fsevents@2.0.6: Please update: there are crash fixes
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.0.6: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.0.6" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/parser@1.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.10.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 11 new dependencies.
```

Once it goes through to the end, if i try to install another package (any package) i.e `npm install bootstrap --save` i keep getting errors like;

```sh
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.0.6: Please update: there are crash fixes
npm WARN rm not removing /home/vagrant/admin/node_modules/.bin/jest as it wasn't installed by /home/vagrant/admin/node_modules/jest
npm WARN rm not removing /home/vagrant/admin/node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs as it wasn't installed by /home/vagrant/admin/node_modules/uglify-js
npm WARN rm not removing /home/vagrant/admin/node_modules/.bin/semver as it wasn't installed by /home/vagrant/admin/node_modules/semver
npm WARN rm not removing /home/vagrant/admin/node_modules/.bin/esparse as it wasn't installed by /home/vagrant/admin/node_modules/esprima
npm WARN rm not removing /home/vagrant/admin/node_modules/.bin/esvalidate as it wasn't installed by /home/vagrant/admin/node_modules/esprima
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.15.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/admin/node_modules/@hapi/topo/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/package.json.1181420959
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/admin/node_modules/@hapi/topo/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/package.json.1181420959'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-08-05T11_56_29_110Z-debug.log
```

I have tried updating the packages using `npm -g update. But still nothing

Any help would be greatly appreciated, its driving me NUTS!

Comment: did you try removing node modules and running npm i?

Comment: @AbhishekAnand yes i have done that. Still nothing

Answer (score 1):

There are [a number of packages on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=npm%20install%20peers) that attempt to solve this very problem in different ways. I've used `npx npm-install-peers` in the past, but I had to run it again after every new install, as the peer dependencies were wiped out on every normal `npm install`.

**Edit:** you might want to add `npm-install-peers` to both `postinstall` and `postuninstall` scripts so you don't have to do it manually each time you (un)install something.

Comment: Hey. I tried using `npm install -g npm-install-peers` and then back to my project folder and `npm install --save bootstrap` ... But its still giving me the same error ... Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @CodeSauce `npm install -g npm-install-peers` just installs the `npm-install-peers` package globally, but doesn't change/execute anything else! 
`npx npm-install-peers` executes it ones und updates the peer dependencies, but doesn't install the `npm-install-peers` package.

Answer (score -1):

I just ran:

```
npm install typescript
```

to install the latest and now I don't see that peer package error. You could also install it global, I suppose:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

which would most certainly work just the same.